# Structure of an API REST with Symfony3

Tags: rest, symfony

I use Symfony for my project and I need to build an API REST.

Technically, I know how to build an API Rest but I don't know how to structurate my others bundle around API REST.

For example :

```
src/
    ApiBundle
    CommentBundle
    PageBundle
```

The ApiBundle allows to create/ delete/ update (etc) a Page or Comment. Do entities (and Forms) must be in ApiBundle or CommentBundle/ PageBundle ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symfony Best Practices - [Organizing Your Business Logic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html):

> For most projects, you should store everything inside the AppBundle. Inside here, you can create whatever directories you want to organize things

Basically you shouldn't make separate bundles for almost every entity (or group or entities) like `Page` or `Comment`, because they will be tightly coupled anyway. So there's no gain on that.

Actually that's one of biggest misunderstanding of what bundles are. You shouldn't create a separate bundle unless it's independent from other bundles and it's target is to be reusable and pretty generic code.

By the way I personally prefer to keep domain layer (entities e.g.) outside of any bundle. That way it's not even coupled to the framework.

Comment: For my personal experience : when symfony2 came out it was  recommended to create bundles for almoste everything... In Symfony3 this is more flexible since we can choose in the generate:bundle command if the bundle will be shared accros several applications.

Comment: @ousmane you're right about earlier recommendation, but that was quickly rejected by community and so their best practices changed soon too. It's been long time before S3 came out. That just didn't work. :)